# Formula to replace values If cell is not empty (e.g."Y" for yes) to be replaced by an absolute reference cell?

Tags: excel-formula

This may be simple - I am using a costing sheet that has been built to be somewhat of a checklist, in a row of names. I want to be able to tick or use text "Y" (Yes) if costings should be added to a person in the same cell the text was entered.

Example:
J$10 refers to a cost, I want this reference to replace entered text in a cell without having to manually click to replace certain values. In short - replacing specified text with another cell with an absolute reference of its own($).
Formula for:
IF "Y" is entered replace to J$10

at the moment I am manually pasting "J$10" (refers to a standard costing sum) next to a row of candidate names but this has a lot of columns per name under predetermined costs selections.

Comment: I can't follow. Maybe posting data or screenshots of what you mean helps explaining what you mean?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if you type "Y" in the cell, you want that "Y" to be replaced by the value that is in another cell, say J$10.  This can't be done in Excel.  A cell can contain a value, or it can contain a script (a formula) that tells the cell how to derive its own value, but it can't do both.  As soon as you type a "Y" in the cell, that "Y" replaces whatever formula was in the cell.  In other words, the formula that tests "if I am equal to Y, then make me equal to J$10" will be erased and replaced by the "Y", leaving no formula behind to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

What Max R is hinting at: use another column for this.

J$10 holds a sum, if you were to use column K for the "Y" value, then your formula in column L would need to be:

```
=if(K10 = "Y", J$10, 0)
```

assuming you want to sum all with a "Y": you can do this on column L